# Output as array

Tags: php

```
       $result = mysql_query(" SELECT p.page_url AS url,
                               COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
                               FROM page p, word w, occurrence o
                               WHERE p.page_id = o.page_id AND
                               w.word_id = o.word_id AND
                               w.word_word = \"$keyword\"
                               GROUP BY p.page_id
                               ORDER BY occurrences DESC
                               " );

$output = "<loginsuccess>";

for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )      {


$output .="<keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur><queryTime>".(substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5))."</queryTime>";
}

$output .= "</loginsuccess>";
print ($output);
```

I am gettign the output in XML, instead i want it in array... how to achieve this.

The code below is not working...

```
$ret = array();
for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )      {

     $tmp['url'] = $row['url'];
     $tmp['occurrences'] = $row['occurrences'];

     $ret[] = $tmp;

}
 return $ret;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question? The $result you get from mysql_query() is already an array. The php code above then takes that array and formats it as XML.

Comment: Mate, i need it to communicate with Flex, i am not able to get the final output when its in xml... so thought of converting it to an array.... but when i do so... its not working.

Comment: @theband: Rephrase your question or post a follow-up question that asks how to query a MySQL database using PHP and transmit the result to Flex. We can't help you if you don't ask the right question.

Comment: Do you want your php array to be an array inside your flex application?

Answer (score 7):

You're already getting the results in an array when you call `mysql_fetch_array($result)`. That's what [mysql_fetch_array](http://ca.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) does.

Unless you want some other kind of array format? If so, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Agreed. You've already got the array, that's what you're using to build the XML. If you don't want the XML... don't build it?

Comment: $ret = array();
for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )  {

     $tmp['url'] = $row['url'];
     $tmp['occurrences'] = $row['occurrences'];
     
     $ret[] = $tmp;

}
 return $ret;

Can i do something like this.

Comment: @theband: Why not just `return mysql_fetch_array($result)`? Why are you overcomplicating things?

Comment: when i try to return $row... i am not able to get in my flex application the values. 

girdId.dataprovider = event.result as Array 

This is not fetching the array values from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Note:** If you won't wrap it in `<pre>` tags, the output will be difficult to read as it will appear all on one line

Answer (score 1):

A **for-loop** is only to be used in an incremental fashion, you attempted to use it in place of a **while** loop.  This isn't "do 1,000 times" but "do while we have a row to use".

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $tmp['url'] = $row['url'];
  $tmp['occurrences'] = $row['occurrences'];
  $ret[] = $tmp;
}
return $ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so, notice the here-doc style of writing the SQL statement. I find it very helpful. Also I would suggest rewriting the SQL to use JOINs instead of crowding the WHERE clause with join criteria.

```
$sql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT p.page_url AS url, COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
FROM page p, word w, occurrence o
WHERE p.page_id = o.page_id AND
w.word_id = o.word_id AND
w.word_word = "$keyword"
GROUP BY p.page_id
ORDER BY occurrences DESC;
EOSQL;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('failed to execute the query');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r ($row);
}
```

Hope this is roughly what you're after

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your $tmp array before using it.